# python - execute shell command with DISPLAY specified?

Tags: python, shell

I read through a lot of the answers but can't figure out how to execute a command which I currently execute using `cron` from `subprocess` or something better?

```
# cron command
00 16 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:10 /path/to/shell/script.sh > log/file.log 2>&1
```

The `DISPLAY` is `Xvfb`.

Comment: Use `os.env` to set the environment variable, then use `subprocess.Popen()` to run the script.

Comment: @Barmar how would I go about doing that? The `DISPLAY=:10` is initiated. I tried checking `os.env()` but got a >AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'env'

Comment: Sorry, it's `os.environ`. So `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':10'`

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable using `os.environ`, then run the command using the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':10'
with open('log/file.log') as out:
    subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/shell/script.sh'], stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: That's true, but unless the Python script is using the DISPLAY environment variable for other things, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: There are mutliple scripts being run using `cron` which are utilizing the `DISPLAY`. I am not sure if this affects the code though. I am getting a >Error: process is already running.

Comment: That's an unrelated issue. If `script.sh` only allows itself to be run once, you can't run it from both `cron` and from your Python script at the same time. It has nothing to do with `DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `env=` argument to `subprocess.Popen`, you can change the environment only for the child process, without modifying the environment of the Python process itself:

```
import subprocess
import os

with open('log/file.log') as out:
    subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/shell/script.sh'],
                     env=dict(os.environ, DISPLAY=":10"),
                     stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: I get an TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'. Its from the `env=(dict(os.environ) | {"DISPLAY": ":10"})` trying to fix it.

Comment: Which version of Python? Works fine on 3.9

Comment: Oh, I am using: `3.6.9`

Comment: @Sid, how about `env=dict(os.environ, DISPLAY=":10")`?